# Microservice for text search only

Tags: microservices

I have a monolith (a big one) and I need text search capabilities.

Is it correct from architectural point of view
to create a new microservice that only returns a text search query result?

I mean say I have a user that want to search something but instead of the monolith doing the work it only accept the user input and calls the microservice that doing the text search work

Answer (score 0):

It depends on that how you design your database. according to your monolith it seems that you have one database. if you create a service for just text searching, i think it's not a good idea. the first thing in microservice is that per service has its own database and the services should not depend each other.
and for text searching the best database is NoSql.
if you can separate your database that can be happened. but if you want to separate database you should think for syncing data of them,(for your text searching) which this has its own patterns and of course its problems. I think so if you have time(and if you really need microservices), refactoring your monolith service to microservice, if you don't, the monolith is not that so bad

Comment: I do have one DB for my monolith. I thought to use CDC pattern and to use dedicate DB for the search microservice only

Comment: @user1409534 CDC pattern is useful for syncing data but you should use something like Kafka or other tools for implementing this pattern which it has its own cost in production. if your system is so big that need to use these tools and patterns, then you can use it. but according to monolith system, using these patterns and tools for separate just one part of it, I think it has no value and don't solve any problem.

Comment: I see...I guess I'll stick with the monolith for now..thank you :-)

Comment: @user1409534 you're welcome. I have experience using large tools and patterns for system and I realized that Given the challenges and costs they have, it's better not use them until we really need them.